# Problema com número perfeito em C

Tags: c, ponteiro, alocação

Estou tendo problemas para mostrar se o número é perfeito, quando coloco 6, diz que não é perfeito, e posso usar apenas ponteiro e alocação dinâmica. Alguém saberia como me ajudar?

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <locale.h>

int perfectNumber(int fNumber) {
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i < fNumber; ++i) {
        sum += i;
        if(fNumber % sum == 0) {
            return 0; // It's perfect
        } else {
            return -1; // it isn't perfect
        }
    }
}

int perfectVerify(int fSecondNumber) {
    if(fSecondNumber == 1) {
        return 1;
    }
    if(perfectNumber(fSecondNumber) == 0) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

int main()  {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");

    int *number;
    number = malloc(sizeof(int));

    printf("Digite um número inteiro: ");
    scanf("%d", number);

    if(perfectNumber(*number) == 1) {
        printf("%d Um número perfeito\n", *number);
    } else {
        printf("%d Não é um número perfeito", *number);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Seu algoritmo para verificação se o número é perfeito está errado. Você só deve somar se for um divisor e não somar todos os números.

Comment: `int sum = 0;` e `int i = 1;` quebram a regra "posso usar apenas ponteiro e alocação dinâmica".

Comment: Te recomendo, meu caro, a fazer um teste de mesa. Tenta resolver por ti mesmo, em vez de buscar uma solução na internet, não é tão complicado. Isso te ajudará a melhorar como programador...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segundo a Wikipedia, um número perfeito é um número natural para o qual a soma de todos os seus divisores naturais próprios (excluindo ele mesmo) é igual ao próprio número.

Por exemplo, o número 28 é perfeito, pois:

```
28 = 1 + 2 + 4 + 7 + 14
```

Assim sendo, segue uma função (testada e comentada) capaz de calcular se um número inteiro é ou não perfeito, veja só:

```
int eh_perfeito( int numero )
{
    int resto = 0;
    int soma = 0;
    int i = 0;

    /* Para todos os numeros entre 1 e o numero em questao menos 1... */
    for( i = 1; i <= (numero - 1); i++ )
    {
        /* Verifica se eh um divisor natural */
        resto = numero % i;

        /* Se for um divisor natural, inclui na soma */
        if(resto == 0)
            soma += i;
    }

    /* Verifica se a soma eh igual ao numero */
    if( soma == numero )
        return 1; /* Eh perfeito */

    /* Nao eh perfeito*/
    return 0;
}
```

Agora, vamos testar a função passando um numero `inteiro` que foi dinamicamente alocado, veja só:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int eh_perfeito( int numero )
{
    int resto = 0;
    int soma = 0;
    int i = 0;

    for( i = 1; i <= (numero - 1); i++ )
    {
        resto = numero % i;

        if(resto == 0)
            soma += i;
    }

    if( soma == numero )
        return 1;

    return 0;
}

int main( void )
{
    /* Aloca memoria para acomodar o numero */
    int * pnumero = (int*) malloc( sizeof(int) );

    /* Le o numero do console */
    printf( "Digite um numero inteiro: ");
    scanf( "%d", pnumero );

    /* Verifica se eh um numero perfeito */
    if( eh_perfeito(*pnumero) )
        printf("Numero Perfeito!\n");
    else
        printf("Numero NAO Perfeito!\n");

    /* libera memoria alocada */
    free(pnumero);

    return 0;
}
```

Testando:

```
Digite um numero inteiro: 6
Numero Perfeito!

Digite um numero inteiro: 100
Numero NAO Perfeito!

Digite um numero inteiro: 101 
Numero NAO Perfeito!

Digite um numero inteiro: 99
Numero NAO Perfeito!

Digite um numero inteiro: 28
Numero Perfeito!

Digite um numero inteiro: 496
Numero Perfeito!
```

Answer (score 1):

### Vejamos...

Você aparenta entender bem o que é um número perfeito. Portanto, não vou me delongar nessa área.

O que vejo como problema:

- Uso de apenas ponteiros e memória dinâmica;
- Execução correta do algoritmo necessário;

Não há como assumir até que ponto precisa usar somente ponteiros. Vou assumir que *errou apenas no ato de definir os argumentos da função* - que deveriam ser ponteiros. Assim, a `sum` e `i` ficam livres para serem usados sem necessidade de alocação dinâmica por serem locais temporários e `number` vira ponteiro dentro das funções.

Em `perfectNumber(int fNumber)`, *o erro está em incrementar* `sum` *sempre*. Você deve apenas incrementar se a divisão de resto (`%`) resultar em zero.

A função `perfectNumber(int fSecondNumber)` é *desnecessária*. Só a lógica contida em `perfectNumber(...)` já basta.

### Algoritmo

Construí um **algoritmo** baseando-me no seu. Mudei o nome de `perfectNumber` para `isPerfect` para ficar mais elegante e lógico em uma declaração `if`/`else`. Também arrumei os problemas que apontei e adequei o código ao estilo que costumo usar por achar mais claro e **enxuto**.

**Função** `isPerfect(...)`:

```
int isPerfect(int *number) {

    size_t i;   /* Boa prática para laços: usar size_t */
    int    sum;

    sum = 0;

    for( i = 1; i < (size_t) *number; ++i ) if( *number % i == 0 ) sum += i;

    if( sum == *number && *number > 0 ) return 1; /* É perfeito */
    else                                return 0; /* Não é perfeito */

}
```

**Função** `main(...)`:

```
int main( void )  {

    int *number;


    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");


    number = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));

    printf("\nDigite um número natural: ");
    scanf("%d", number);


    if( isPerfect( number ) ) printf("%d é perfeito\n\n", *number);
    else                      printf("%d não é perfeito\n\n", *number);


    return 0;

}
```

Após executar o código, temos a seguinte **entrada/saída**:

```
1 não é perfeito
...
5 não é perfeito
6 é perfeito
7 não é perfeito
...
27 não é perfeito
28 é perfeito
```

Uma versão com entrada por meio de argumento ao programa pode ser vista [aqui](https://github.com/jfcandidofilho/stackoverflow/tree/master/370931).